# Mouse Capture and Selection

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse

I have a control, that moves around alot of different controls inside of it in the form of a grid. So basically, none of the container control is shown at any point. But i do have capture of all the mousedown and mousemove events of the controls inside. What id like to do, is create an effect alot like the desktop of a windows computer, where you can drag, and every control that is inside of the mouse's drag will be thrown in a list, and when the mouse is released i can perform an action on all the selected items. Is this possible?

Comment: You lost me at "I have a control that moves controls".  Link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/89e10ad5-49d3-45f8-8d18-1b8a90a9cfe9

Comment: Sorry, @nobugz: I have a class that inherits from the Winforms class UserControl, and it has controls inside of it, that it rearranges and moves around

Comment: Can you show some code, that you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with some trial and error i solved my own question.
in each of my childs controls, i did this:

```
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pnt = this.PointToScreen(e.Location);
        base.OnMouseDown(new MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks, pnt.X, pnt.Y, e.Delta));
    }
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pnt = this.PointToScreen(e.Location);
        base.OnMouseMove(new MouseEventArgs(e.Button, e.Clicks, pnt.X, pnt.Y, e.Delta));
    }
```

to make the cursor position usable from the container control, and in the container i did this:

```
        #region Lambda
        item.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler((a, b) =>
        {
            MessageBase hovering = this.GetChildAtPoint(tr_MouseCurrentPoint) as MessageBase;
            if (b.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                tr_MouseDown = true;
                tr_MouseDownPoint = this.PointToClient(b.Location);
                mouseupdate();
                foreach (var t in tr_CurrentlySelected)
                {
                    t.Key.Selected = false;
                }
                tr_CurrentlySelected.Clear();
                if (hovering != null && tr_CurrentlySelected.ContainsKey(hovering) == false)
                {
                    tr_CurrentlySelected.Add(hovering, new MouseCoordinateStore(tr_MouseDown, tr_MouseDownPoint, tr_MouseCurrentPoint, tr_MouseDifference));
                    hovering.Selected = true;
                    tr_LastHoveredOver = hovering;
                }
            }
            else if (b.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                if (hovering.Selected == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Show Right Click Logic Here");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var t in tr_CurrentlySelected)
                    {
                        t.Key.Selected = false;
                    }
                    tr_CurrentlySelected.Clear();
                    if (hovering != null && tr_CurrentlySelected.ContainsKey(hovering) == false)
                    {
                        tr_CurrentlySelected.Add(hovering, new MouseCoordinateStore(tr_MouseDown, tr_MouseDownPoint, tr_MouseCurrentPoint, tr_MouseDifference));
                        hovering.Selected = true;
                        tr_LastHoveredOver = hovering;
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Show Right Click Logic Here");
                }
            }
        });
        item.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler((a, b) => { tr_MouseDown = false; mouseupdate(); });
        item.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler((a, b) => { 
            tr_MouseCurrentPoint = this.PointToClient(b.Location); 
            mouseupdate();
            if (tr_MouseDown)
            {
                MessageBase hovering = this.GetChildAtPoint(tr_MouseCurrentPoint) as MessageBase;
                if (hovering != null)
                {
                    if (tr_CurrentlySelected.ContainsKey(hovering) == false)
                    {
                        tr_CurrentlySelected.Add(hovering, new MouseCoordinateStore(tr_MouseDown, tr_MouseDownPoint, tr_MouseCurrentPoint, tr_MouseDifference));
                        tr_LastHoveredOver = hovering;
                        hovering.Selected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int ind = hovering.Index;
                        List<MessageBase> ItemsToRemove = new List<MessageBase>();
                        if (tr_MouseDifference.Y < 0) // Y is negative
                        {
                            foreach (var dic in tr_CurrentlySelected)
                            {
                                if (dic.Key.Index < ind)
                                {
                                    ItemsToRemove.Add(dic.Key);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else //Y is positive
                        {
                            foreach (var dic in tr_CurrentlySelected)
                            {
                                if (dic.Key.Index > ind)
                                {
                                    ItemsToRemove.Add(dic.Key);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        foreach (var dic in ItemsToRemove)
                        {
                            tr_CurrentlySelected.Remove(dic);
                            dic.Selected = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        item.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler((a, b) =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (b.KeyData == Keys.Down)
                {
                    MessageBase hovering = ControlCollection[tr_LastHoveredOver.Index + 1];
                    foreach (var t in tr_CurrentlySelected)
                    {
                        t.Key.Selected = false;
                    }
                    tr_CurrentlySelected.Clear();
                    if (hovering != null && tr_CurrentlySelected.ContainsKey(hovering) == false)
                    {
                        tr_CurrentlySelected.Add(hovering, null);
                        hovering.Selected = true;
                        tr_LastHoveredOver = hovering;
                    }
                }
                else if (b.KeyData == Keys.Up)
                {
                    MessageBase hovering = ControlCollection[tr_LastHoveredOver.Index - 1];
                    foreach (var t in tr_CurrentlySelected)
                    {
                        t.Key.Selected = false;
                    }
                    tr_CurrentlySelected.Clear();
                    if (hovering != null && tr_CurrentlySelected.ContainsKey(hovering) == false)
                    {
                        tr_CurrentlySelected.Add(hovering, null);
                        hovering.Selected = true;
                        tr_LastHoveredOver = hovering;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        });
        #endregion
```

obviously there is some other things happening elsewhere, but thats the basic just of it. Thanks for the one answer i got, allthough i already knew about that i appriciate every and all answers i get :) thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Register for OnMouseDown, OnMouseMove, OnMouseUp events.

1. [OnMouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousedown.aspx) get the control's position and focus underneath the mouse.
2. [OnMouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousemove.aspx), set the position of the control with mouse position.
3. [OnMouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseup.aspx) release the control focus.

Checkout the [example](http://blog.ninethsense.com/move-a-control-with-mose-on-form/).

Comment: @Tommy: Sorry if it didnt help. I was after the question ` Is this possible?`, just so it may help you get started.